# Async load image on swift / ios?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

here is my situation, ( please be aware i'm starting on iOS dev :) ).

I have a list of feed where the data are beign fetch from firebase, each feed get an image and title in a table view.

I'm looking for a way, that if the user come back to the app without any internet connection, to still display those data, whic have been display before that.

Currently, I'm using this to display the data:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftyJSON

var posts = [Post]()
var selectedIndexPath: Int = 10

class FeedVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var feedTableView: UITableView!

private var readPosts: ObserveTask?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    feedTableView.dataSource = self
    feedTableView.delegate = self

    readPosts = Post.observeList(from: Post.parentReference.queryOrdered(byChild: "privacy").queryEqual(toValue: false))

    {
        observedPosts in

        posts = observedPosts.reversed()
        self.feedTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell  {
    let cell = self.feedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell")! as UITableViewCell


 let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView



    let titleLabel = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
    let linkLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel

    titleLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].title
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

    linkLabel.text = posts[indexPath.row].link
    linkLabel.numberOfLines = 0



    Storage.getImage(with: posts[indexPath.row].imageUrl){
        postPic in
        imageView.image = postPic
    }

    return cell

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard posts[indexPath.row].title != "COMING SOON" else {
        return
    }
           selectedIndexPath = indexPath.row
          self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "push", sender: self)
            self.feedTableView.reloadData()    }


}
```

How is this possible to do ? I've been looking from NSUR function, is this a good start ?

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Have you tried my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Use core data to store images or

If You probably don't want to store these images in Core Data, since that can impact performance if the data set grows too large. Better to write the images to files.

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
```

This pulls out PNG data of the image you've captured. From here, you can write it to a file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory 
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
```

Reading it later works the same way. Build the path like we just did above, then:

```
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
```

What you'll probably want to do is make a method that creates path strings for you, since you don't want that code littered everywhere. It might look like this:

```
- (NSString *)documentsPathForFileName:(NSString *)name
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:name]; 
}
```

Hope that's helpful.